# Compiling Java programs in command line

Tags: java

Do I have to run set Class and Set ClassPath in Commandline every time for compiling Java programs with these commands

```
set class ="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin";  
set classpath="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib\rt.jar"; 
C:\>Javac Test1.java
C:\>Java Test1
```

even I added up folder up to bin in environment variable for setting up the environment variable.If I do not run SET CLASS and SET CLASSPATH, I get an error Error: Could not find or load main class Test1

Please answer thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i would do is :

1) Add jdk path to PATH.
2) Create a folder with all my classes in , the cd to that folder "javac" every class and then "java" the one containing the "main" method.

Answer (score 0):

You also need the path where **your** compiled class files are in your classpath!

You only included the tools.jar - but not your class file(s).

When compiling, you should only point to those JVM classes, but when running your application, your classes need to be found too!